# MCMCpack suppress MCMCmetrop1R function output

Tags: r, mcmc

The function MCMCmetrop1R has the option to suppress its output to the screen using the option `verbose=FALSE` or `verbose=0`. however this doesn't stop the function reporting the following when the function completes its operation.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The Metropolis acceptance rate was 0.15862
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

I have tried using the `invisible()` function around the MEMCmetrop1R function but this did not make any difference.
Are there any other suggestion to stop the function reporting the acceptance rate?

Answer (score 0):

As I came across the same problem today, here is my solution: You can use `capture.output` or `captureOutput()` from the `R.utils` package. Latter is said to be faster (see http://www.jottr.org/2014/05/captureOutput.html).

```
R.utils::captureOutput(expr={
  post.sample <- MCMCmetrop1R(loglik, theta.init = c(0, 1, 1), ...)
})
```

Note, that this effects all other outputs as well. So, if you set `verbose > 0`, this will not show up either.